# print values of all items in array JAVASCRIPT / d3

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

Sorry if it's a bit rookie:

I have a csv file turned into array with property-value duos.

```
console.log(data);
console.log(data[0].property_name);
console.log(data.property_name);
```

first and second line work perfectly
the third line doesn't work (returns undefined)

Comment: because `data` is a array, and the elements of the array havin the property `property_name`, and not the array

Comment: what would be the best practice to get to console.log the property_name of all elements of the array?

Comment: `console.log(data.map(function(item){return item.property_name}));`

Answer (score 2):

Data is an array. Each element in the array presumably has a property_name. So data[0], or the first element in the array, works just fine. If you want all the values printed out use a for loop or foreach loop or print each out like...

```
console.log(data[0].property_name);
console.log(data[1].property_name);
```

**For Loop**

```
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    console.log(data[i].property_name);
}
```

Comment: Thank you :) I was hoping that there would be a "nicer" way than using a loop.

Comment: If you think loops are not nice then programming is going to be rough.

Comment: they're super nice, but some functions can be nicer :)

Comment: You need to get used to loops. They are literally one of the foundations of programming. No shame in printing out each with the index, but you will save time in the future learning to understand a loop and where to place debug code.

Answer (score 1):

After getting your data from your csv using d3 you will get an object prop/val. You can use Object.values to get the values from the props.

```js
var csv = {
  city: "seattle",
  state: "WA",
  population: "652405",
  landarea: "83.9"
};
console.log(Object.values(csv));
```

And for an array of Objects

```js
var csv = [{
  city: "seattle",
  state: "WA",
  population: "652405",
  landarea: "83.9"
}, {
  city: "moSat",
  state: "moWA",
  population: "mo652405",
  landarea: "mo83.9"
}];

var val = csv.map(x => Object.values(x));
console.log(val);
```

Comment: My CSV created 5 ovject, each with it's own few object/value pairs.

obj1 
name: a
size: 7

obj2
name: b
size: 5...

I was able to represent a simple array (var array = [4, 6, 2...]) with a d3 based function.

I wish to use the same function on the VALUES from the csv file

is that possible?

Comment: That's fine you can use it in the same way, this all depends on how your CSV is setup. ill update my answer to show you